# ransack_alias not doing anything in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I use Ransack for my search forms and I am attempting to use `ransack_alias` to shorten the queries. However, when I perform a search, the aliased fields don't filter the query at all. I have simplified my form to have only one simple alias and it doesn't seem to work.

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ransack_alias :ec, :email_cont
end
```

index.html.haml

```
= search_form_for @q, url: users_path, html: {method: :get} do |f|
  = f.label :ec
  = f.search_field :ec
  = f.submit 'Search'
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the controller:

```
>> User.count
10

>> User.ransack({email_cont: "test@email.com"}).result.count
(93.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" ILIKE '%test@email\.com%')
1

>> params[:q]
{"ec" => "test@email.com"}

>> User.ransack(params[:q]).result.count
(28.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"
10

>> User._ransack_aliases
{"ec" => "email_cont"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ransack_alias` is for aliasing attributes, but not comparison key.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ransack_alias :e, :email
end

> User.ransack({'e_cont' => "user"}).result.count 
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" LIKE '%user%')
```